# Inputs side-by-side in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to put 3 inputs side-by-side. 
I have a code as follows and in every iterate I want three components side-by-side.
Is it possible?

```
{
    this.state.features.length > 0 ?
        this.state.features.map((feature) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <BooleanInput key={feature} source={this.assignIsFeatureActiveProp(feature)} label={feature} />
                    <DisabledInput source="id" label="Value" defaultValue={feature} />
                    <TextInput source={this.assignFeatureValueProp(feature)} label="Value" />
                </div>
            )
        })
        :
        null
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass style props, for example, use the following style.

`style={{ display: 'inline', float: 'left', marginLeft: '20px' }}`

The above code will looks like

```
{
    this.state.features.length > 0 ?
        this.state.features.map((feature) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <BooleanInput key={feature} source={this.assignIsFeatureActiveProp(feature)} label={feature} style={{ display: 'inline', float: 'left', marginLeft: '20px' }} />
                    <DisabledInput source="id" label="Value" defaultValue={feature} style={{ display: 'inline', float: 'left', marginLeft: '20px' }} />
                    <TextInput source={this.assignFeatureValueProp(feature)} label="Value" style={{ display: 'inline', float: 'left', marginLeft: '20px' }} />
                </div>
            )
        })
        :
        null
}
```

Comment: Yeah, It worked. I supposed I tried something like that but I guess I missed something, thank you :)